# What is the major product of bromobutane and sodium ethoxide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, elimination

[image]

I know that the it is S<sub>N</sub>2 reaction and $\ce{Br}$ is the leaving group. Second Carbon(from right side) is the beta carbon. As the $\ce{Br}$ group leaves, $\ce{OH}$ will create a bond with one of the beta hydrogen and will lead to formation of a double bond between the second and third carbon.
Can someone please check and explain why the structure i got for major product is wrong ?

Comment: Do you mean E2…

Answer (score 1):

This is an S<sub>N</sub>2 mechanism, not an elimination mechanism. The $\ce{NaOEt}$ is not bulky, and the leaving group is primary. Because of this $\ce{^-OEt}$ will attack the carbon where $\ce{Br}$ is attached via an S<sub>N</sub>2 backside attack. This will replace the $\ce{ Br}$ with $\ce{^-OCH2CH3}$.

I remember organic was a bit of a rough time. Here is a flow chart I used back in organic from [Clutch Prep](https://www.clutchprep.com/).[image: "Big Daddy Flow Chart" by Clutch Prep]

Comment: Isn't $\ce{EtO^-}$ a hard nucleophile? Wouldn't that favor the elimination product isnteas of substitution?

Comment: @AlyChem: What about solvent effect?

Comment: There are always exceptions, but typically even a hard nucleophile would undergo SN2 because of the primary leaving group. Solvent effects from what I've seen are definitely important, but not usually the driving force behind determining the major product. I'm definitely not an organic chemist, though.

Answer (score 0):

You may be knowing that  S<sub>N</sub>2 do not undergo $carbocation$ $rearrangement$. Therefore your product is incorrect. Now The $\ce{NaOEt}$ is not a bulky group . Because of this $\ce{^-OEt}$ will attack the carbon where $\ce{Br}$ is attached via an S<sub>N</sub>2 backside attack. This will replace the $\ce{ Br}$ with $\ce{^-OCH2CH3}$.